# Converting svg path to polygon in javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, polygon

i am trying to convert an svg path to an svg polygon in javascript. i found this function to crawl along the path and extract its coordinates.

```
    var length = path.getTotalLength();
    var p=path.getPointAtLength(0);
    var stp=p.x+","+p.y;
    
    for(var i=1; i<length; i++){
    
        p=path.getPointAtLength(i);
        stp=stp+" "+p.x+","+p.y;
        
    }
```

this works but it returns some hundreds of points for a polygon that has only six points originally. how would i get only the necessary points (all paths are straight lines, no curves)

```js
var path = $.find("path")[0];

var len = path.getTotalLength();
var p = path.getPointAtLength(0);
var stp = p.x + "," + p.y;
var newp;

for (var i = 1; i < len; i++) {
  newp = path.getPointAtLength(i);
  if (newp.x != p.x && newp.y != p.y) {
    p = newp;
  } else {
    continue;
  }
  stp = stp + " " + p.x + " " + p.y;

}

$('#poly').text(stp);
```

```css
pre {
  display: block;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg version="1.1" id="Ebene_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="425.2px" height="303.31px" viewBox="0 0 425.2 303.31" enable-background="new 0 0 425.2 303.31" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
    <path id="path" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M256.768,227.211h-33.013l4.902-65.682l-40.357,59.06
        l-26.654-37.931l0.292-0.298L264.865,77.415L256.768,227.211z M224.833,226.211h30.987l7.903-146.205L162.942,182.764
        l25.346,36.069l41.643-60.94L224.833,226.211z"/>
</g>
</svg>

<code>
<pre id="poly">
</pre>
</code>
```

Comment: I would bet that you need to determine when one of the x or y values changes since the last iteration, meaning that the direction has changed. Only then should you grab that point.

Comment: that reduces the number of points but it's still around 1000 points.. i need 6.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a jsFiddle with the SVG and this code?

Comment: sure.. here u go.. http://jsfiddle.net/AudEh/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ok got it.. the function getPathSegAtLength() returns the number of the actual path segment. with that it's easy then.

```
    var len = path.getTotalLength();
    var p=path.getPointAtLength(0);
    var seg = path.getPathSegAtLength(0);
    var stp=p.x+","+p.y;

    for(var i=1; i<len; i++){

        p=path.getPointAtLength(i);

        if (path.getPathSegAtLength(i)>seg) {

        stp=stp+" "+p.x+","+p.y;
        seg = path.getPathSegAtLength(i);

        }

    }
```

Comment: getPathSegAtLength has been removed. Please check 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGPathElement

Answer (score 1):

`path.getPointAtLength()` is good for rough purposes where you don't need both speed and quality. If you get every pixel, you get thousands of points, but still the quality is low, because SVG path can have decimal values, eg. 0.1, 0.2.

If you want more precision by calling eg. `path.getPointAtLength(0.1)` you get easily tens of thousands of points in complex paths and the process last seconds or tens of seconds. And after that you have to reduce the count of point (https://stackoverflow.com/a/15976155/1691517), which last again seconds. But still the quality can be low, if wrong points are removed.

Better techique is to first convert all path segments to cubic curves eg. using [Raphael's](http://raphaeljs.com/) path2curve() and then use some adaptive method (http://antigrain.com/research/adaptive_bezier/) to convert cubic segments to points and you get at the same time both the speed and quality. And after that there is no need to reduce points because the adaptive process itself has parameters to adjust the quality.

I have made a function that does all that and I'm going to publish it when it is enough optimized for speed. The quality and reliability seems to be 100% after testing with thousands of random paths and the speed is yet significantly faster than with `path.getPointAtLength()`.

Comment: thanks for the effort but in my case i'm only working with straight lines, as i said, so this wont be necessary

Comment: @Timo - Did you ever publish your algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over the segments, use something like this:

```
var segList = path.normalizedPathSegList; // or .pathSegList

for(var i=1; i<segList.numberOfSegments; i++){
    var seg = segList.getItem(i);
}
```

If you want to reduce the number of vertices, then you can use [Simplify.js](http://mourner.github.com/simplify-js/) as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13730062/simplifying-svg-path-strings-by-reducing-number-of-nodes/13738156#13738156).

Answer (score 0):

> how would i get only the necessary points (all paths are straight
> lines, no curves)

If your path actually contains only linetos you can take a shortcut to retrieve polygon vertices by parsing the path data.

### 1. Polygon vertices from path data

This approach requires to:

- parse the path data from the `d` attribute
- convert all commands to absolute values
- convert shorthand commands `h`, `v` to their longhand `l` equivalents

#### Test if path data is a polygon

We can check whether a path could be represented as a polygon by inspecting its `d` attribute like so:

```
function pathIsPolygon(d) {
  // any beziers or arc commands?
  let isPolygon = /[csqta]/gi.test(d) ? false : true
  return isPolygon;
}
```

We're basically testing if the path data string contains any bézier or arc commands. If not (no `c`,`s`,`q`,`t`,`a` commands): we can proceed to retrieve vertices from the path data by getting the last couple of values representing the final on-path point. This check improves both performance and accuracy as we avoid unnecessary iterative `pointAtLength()` calculations and retain the original polygonal geometry of the path.

```js
/**
 * 1. is polygon:
 */
let path = document.getElementById("path");
let poly = document.getElementById("poly");

// parse pathdata
let d = path.getAttribute("d");
let pathData = parsePathDataNormalized(d);

/**
 * check if path is already a polygon:
 * just return the final command points
 */
let vertices;
let isPolygon = pathIsPolygon(d);
if (isPolygon) {
  console.log(path.id, "is polygon");
  vertices = getPathDataVertices(pathData);
}

//apply
let ptAtt = vertices
  .map((pt) => {
    return Object.values(pt);
  })
  .flat()
  .join(" ");
poly.setAttribute("points", ptAtt);

//output vertices/point array
verticesOut.value = JSON.stringify(vertices, null, ' ');

function pathIsPolygon(d) {
  // any beziers or arc commands?
  let isPolygon = /[csqta]/gi.test(d) ? false : true;
  return isPolygon;
}

function getPathDataVertices(pathData) {
  let polyPoints = [];
  pathData.forEach((com) => {
    let values = com.values;
    // get final on path point from last 2 values
    if (values.length) {
      let pt = {
        x: values[values.length - 2],
        y: values[values.length - 1]
      };
      polyPoints.push(pt);
    }
  });
  return polyPoints;
}

/**
 * Standalone pathData parser
 * returns a pathData array compliant
 * with the w3C SVGPathData interface draft
 * https://svgwg.org/specs/paths/#InterfaceSVGPathData
 */

function parsePathDataNormalized(d) {
  d = d
    .replace(/[\n\r\t|,]/g, " ")
    .trim()
    .replace(/(\d)-/g, "$1 -")
    .replace(/(\.)(?=(\d+\.\d+)+)(\d+)/g, "$1$3 ");

  let pathData = [];
  let cmdRegEx = /([mlcqazvhst])([^mlcqazvhst]*)/gi;
  let commands = d.match(cmdRegEx);

  // valid command value lengths
  let comLengths = {m: 2,a: 7,c: 6,h: 1,l: 2,q: 4,s: 4,t: 2,v: 1,z: 0
  };

  // offsets for absolute conversion
  let offX, offY, lastX, lastY;

  for (let c = 0; c < commands.length; c++) {
    let com = commands[c];
    let type = com.substring(0, 1);
    let typeRel = type.toLowerCase();
    let typeAbs = type.toUpperCase();
    let isRel = type === typeRel;
    let chunkSize = comLengths[typeRel];

    // split values to array
    let values = com.substring(1, com.length).trim().split(" ").filter(Boolean);

    /**
     * A - Arc commands
     * large arc and sweep flags
     * are boolean and can be concatenated like
     */
    if (typeRel === "a" && values.length != comLengths.a) {
      let n = 0,
        arcValues = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        let value = values[i];

        // reset counter
        if (n >= chunkSize) {
          n = 0;
        }
        // if 3. or 4. parameter longer than 1
        if ((n === 3 || n === 4) && value.length > 1) {
          let largeArc = n === 3 ? value.substring(0, 1) : "";
          let sweep = n === 3 ? value.substring(1, 2) : value.substring(0, 1);
          let finalX = n === 3 ? value.substring(2) : value.substring(1);
          let comN = [largeArc, sweep, finalX].filter(Boolean);
          arcValues.push(comN);
          n += comN.length;
        } else {
          arcValues.push(value);
          n++;
        }
      }
      values = arcValues.flat().filter(Boolean);
    }

    // string  to number
    values = values.map(Number);

    // if string contains repeated shorthand commands - split them
    let hasMultiple = values.length > chunkSize;
    let chunk = hasMultiple ? values.slice(0, chunkSize) : values;
    let comChunks = [{
      type: type,
      values: chunk
    }];

    // has implicit or repeated commands – split into chunks
    if (hasMultiple) {
      let typeImplicit = typeRel === "m" ? (isRel ? "l" : "L") : type;
      for (let i = chunkSize; i < values.length; i += chunkSize) {
        let chunk = values.slice(i, i + chunkSize);
        comChunks.push({
          type: typeImplicit,
          values: chunk
        });
      }
    }

    // convert to absolute
    if (c === 0) {
      offX = values[0];
      offY = values[1];
      lastX = offX;
      lastY = offY;
    }

    let typeFirst = comChunks[0].type;
    typeAbs = typeFirst.toUpperCase();

    isRel =
      typeFirst.toLowerCase() === typeFirst && pathData.length ? true : false;

    for (let i = 0; i < comChunks.length; i++) {
      let com = comChunks[i];
      let type = com.type;
      let values = com.values;
      let valuesL = values.length;
      let comPrev = comChunks[i - 1] ?
        comChunks[i - 1] :
        c > 0 && pathData[pathData.length - 1] ?
        pathData[pathData.length - 1] :
        comChunks[i];

      let valuesPrev = comPrev.values;
      let valuesPrevL = valuesPrev.length;
      isRel =
        comChunks.length > 1 ?
        type.toLowerCase() === type && pathData.length :
        isRel;

      if (isRel) {
        com.type = comChunks.length > 1 ? type.toUpperCase() : typeAbs;

        switch (typeRel) {
          case "a":
            com.values = [
              values[0],
              values[1],
              values[2],
              values[3],
              values[4],
              values[5] + offX,
              values[6] + offY
            ];
            break;

          case "h":
          case "v":
            com.values = type === "h" ? [values[0] + offX] : [values[0] + offY];
            break;

          case "m":
          case "l":
          case "t":
            com.values = [values[0] + offX, values[1] + offY];
            break;

          case "c":
            com.values = [
              values[0] + offX,
              values[1] + offY,
              values[2] + offX,
              values[3] + offY,
              values[4] + offX,
              values[5] + offY
            ];
            break;

          case "q":
          case "s":
            com.values = [
              values[0] + offX,
              values[1] + offY,
              values[2] + offX,
              values[3] + offY
            ];
            break;
        }
      }
      // is absolute
      else {
        offX = 0;
        offY = 0;
      }

      // convert shorthands
      let shorthandTypes = ["H", "V", "S", "T"];

      if (shorthandTypes.includes(typeAbs)) {
        let cp1X, cp1Y, cpN1X, cpN1Y, cp2X, cp2Y;
        if (com.type === "H" || com.type === "V") {
          com.values =
            com.type === "H" ? [com.values[0], lastY] : [lastX, com.values[0]];
          com.type = "L";
        } else if (com.type === "T" || com.type === "S") {
          [cp1X, cp1Y] = [valuesPrev[0], valuesPrev[1]];
          [cp2X, cp2Y] =
          valuesPrevL > 2 ? [valuesPrev[2], valuesPrev[3]] : [valuesPrev[0], valuesPrev[1]];

          // new control point
          cpN1X = com.type === "T" ? lastX * 2 - cp1X : lastX * 2 - cp2X;
          cpN1Y = com.type === "T" ? lastY * 2 - cp1Y : lastY * 2 - cp2Y;

          com.values = [cpN1X, cpN1Y, com.values].flat();
          com.type = com.type === "T" ? "Q" : "C";
        }
      }

      pathData.push(com);

      lastX =
        valuesL > 1 ?
        values[valuesL - 2] + offX :
        typeRel === "h" ?
        values[0] + offX :
        lastX;
      lastY =
        valuesL > 1 ?
        values[valuesL - 1] + offY :
        typeRel === "v" ?
        values[0] + offY :
        lastY;
      offX = lastX;
      offY = lastY;
    }
  }
  pathData[0].type = "M";
  return pathData;
}
```

```css
svg {
  overflow: visible;
  width:25%;
}

svg path {
  stroke-width: 2%;
  stroke: #ccc;
}

svg polygon {
  stroke-width: 0.75%;
  marker-start: url(#markerStart);
  marker-mid: url(#markerRound);
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  min-height: 10em;
}
```

```html
<h3>Path is already a polygon</h3>
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 425.2 303.31" enable-background="new 0 0 425.2 303.31" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
    <path id="path" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M256.768,227.211h-33.013l4.902-65.682l-40.357,59.06
        l-26.654-37.931l0.292-0.298L264.865,77.415L256.768,227.211z M224.833,226.211h30.987l7.903-146.205L162.942,182.764
        l25.346,36.069l41.643-60.94L224.833,226.211z"/>
</g>

<polygon id="poly" />
</svg>


<h3>Point/vertices data</h3>
<textarea id="verticesOut"></textarea>


<!-- markers to show commands -->
<svg id="svgMarkers" style="width:0; height:0; position:absolute; z-index:-1;float:left;opacity:0">
<defs>
<marker id="markerStart" overflow="visible" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="5" refY="5" markerUnits="strokeWidth"
markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10" orient="auto-start-reverse">
<circle cx="5" cy="5" r="5" fill="green"></circle>
<marker id="markerRound" overflow="visible" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="5" refY="5"
markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10" orient="auto-start-reverse">
<circle cx="5" cy="5" r="2.5" fill="red"></circle>
</marker>
</defs>
</svg>
```

#### Parsing path data

By parsing the path data we can easily retrieve x and y coordinates from each command to create an array of point objects.
The parsing is done via a custom parsing script trying to be compliant with the suggested [W3C pathdata interface spec draft][1]. This draft is intended to replace the (mostly) deprecated/unsupported `SVGPathSeg` interface (although I won't hold my breath ... this concept is around since 2016).

Worth noting there is still a polyfill. See ["https://github.com/progers/pathseg"][2] .

You can actually use any path data parser (as long as it provides a way to convert commands to all absolute and "unshort" commands like `h`and `v` to `l`) for instance [Jarek Foksa's path-data-polyfill][3] setting the normalize parameter like so `path.getPathData({normalize:true})`.

### 2. Polygon retaining path shape

If a path also contains curves, `getPointAtlength()` may not be ideal as it wont't retain the basic geometry – respecting command final points.

[![pointAtLength() vertices][4]][4]
Despite points are calculated based on equal path length intervals the visual result appears to be rather arbitrary.  We lose the expected symmetry of the original shape.

#### Add points per segment

We can fix this issue by adding vertices according to each segment's length.

```js
let decimals = 2;
let split = 32;

/**
 * 1. is polygon:
 */
let path = document.getElementById('path')
let poly = document.getElementById('poly')
let vertices = getPathPolygonVertices(path, split, decimals);

//apply
let ptAtt = vertices.map(pt => {
  return Object.values(pt)
}).flat().join(' ')
poly.setAttribute('points', ptAtt)


/**
 * 2. has curves:
 */
let path1 = document.getElementById('path1')
let poly1 = document.getElementById('poly1')
let vertices1 = getPathPolygonVertices(path1, split, decimals);

//apply
let ptAtt1 = vertices1.map(pt => {
  return Object.values(pt)
}).flat().join(' ')
poly1.setAttribute('points', ptAtt1)


function getPathPolygonVertices(path, split = 16, decimals = 3) {

  let pts = []
  let ns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'

  // parse pathdata
  let d = path.getAttribute('d')
  let pathData = parsePathDataNormalized(d)

  /**
   * check if path is already polygon:
   * just return the final command points
   */
  let isPolygon = pathIsPolygon(d);
  if (isPolygon) {
    console.log(path.id, 'is polygon');
    pts = getPathDataVertices(pathData)
    return pts
  }

  // target side length
  let totalLength = path.getTotalLength();
  let step = totalLength / split;
  let lastLength = 0;
  let Mvalues = pathData[0].values;
  let M = {
    x: Mvalues[Mvalues.length - 2],
    y: Mvalues[Mvalues.length - 1]
  };

  for (let i = 1; i < pathData.length; i++) {
    let com = pathData[i];
    let comPrev = pathData[i - 1];
    let type = com.type.toLowerCase();
    let [values, valuesPrev] = [com.values, comPrev.values];

    //previous commands final point
    let p0 = {
      x: valuesPrev[valuesPrev.length - 2],
      y: valuesPrev[valuesPrev.length - 1]
    };
    let p = values.length ? {
      x: values[values.length - 2],
      y: values[values.length - 1]
    } : p0;

    if (values.length) {
      // create temporary path to get segment length
      let pathSeg = document.createElementNS(ns, 'path')
      pathSeg.setAttribute('d', `M ${p0.x} ${p0.y} ${com.type} ${com.values.join(' ')}`)
      let segLength = pathSeg.getTotalLength()

      // fit to segment length – keep command end points to better retain shape
      let segSplits = Math.ceil(segLength / step);

      // if lineto: no need to calculate points
      if (type === 'l') {
        pts.push(p0);
        pts.push(p);
      } else {

        for (let s = 0; s < segSplits; s++) {
          let len = lastLength + (segLength / segSplits) * s;
          // get point
          let pt = path.getPointAtLength(len);
          pts.push(pt);
        }
      }
      //remove temorary path
      pathSeg.remove()
      lastLength += segLength;
    }

    // is Z/closepath: add previous end point
    else {
      pts.push(p0);
    }
  }

  //round coordinates
  pts = Array.from(pts).map(pt => {
    return {
      x: +pt.x.toFixed(decimals),
      y: y = +pt.y.toFixed(decimals)
    }
  });

  return pts
}



function pathIsPolygon(d) {
  // any beziers or arc commands?
  let isPolygon = /[csqta]/gi.test(d) ? false : true
  return isPolygon;
}

function getPathDataVertices(pathData) {
  let polyPoints = [];
  pathData.forEach(com => {
    let values = com.values;
    // get final on path point from last 2 values
    if (values.length) {
      let pt = {
        x: values[values.length - 2],
        y: values[values.length - 1]
      }
      polyPoints.push(pt)
    }
  })
  return polyPoints
}



/**
 * Standalone pathData parser
 */
function parsePathDataNormalized(d) {
  d = d
    .replace(/[\n\r\t|,]/g, " ")
    .trim()
    .replace(/(\d)-/g, "$1 -")
    .replace(/(\.)(?=(\d+\.\d+)+)(\d+)/g, "$1$3 ");

  let pathData = [];
  let cmdRegEx = /([mlcqazvhst])([^mlcqazvhst]*)/gi;
  let commands = d.match(cmdRegEx);

  // valid command value lengths
  let comLengths = {
    m: 2,
    a: 7,
    c: 6,
    h: 1,
    l: 2,
    q: 4,
    s: 4,
    t: 2,
    v: 1,
    z: 0
  };

  // offsets for absolute conversion
  let offX, offY, lastX, lastY;

  for (let c = 0; c < commands.length; c++) {
    let com = commands[c];
    let type = com.substring(0, 1);
    let typeRel = type.toLowerCase();
    let typeAbs = type.toUpperCase();
    let isRel = type === typeRel;
    let chunkSize = comLengths[typeRel];

    // split values to array
    let values = com.substring(1, com.length).trim().split(" ").filter(Boolean);

    /**
     * fix A - Arc commands
     */
    if (typeRel === "a" && values.length != comLengths.a) {
      let n = 0,
        arcValues = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        let value = values[i];

        // reset counter
        if (n >= chunkSize) {
          n = 0;
        }
        // if 3. or 4. parameter longer than 1
        if ((n === 3 || n === 4) && value.length > 1) {
          let largeArc = n === 3 ? value.substring(0, 1) : "";
          let sweep = n === 3 ? value.substring(1, 2) : value.substring(0, 1);
          let finalX = n === 3 ? value.substring(2) : value.substring(1);
          let comN = [largeArc, sweep, finalX].filter(Boolean);
          arcValues.push(comN);
          n += comN.length;
        } else {
          // regular
          arcValues.push(value);
          n++;
        }
      }
      values = arcValues.flat().filter(Boolean);
    }

    // string  to number
    values = values.map(Number);
    let hasMultiple = values.length > chunkSize;
    let chunk = hasMultiple ? values.slice(0, chunkSize) : values;
    let comChunks = [{
      type: type,
      values: chunk
    }];

    if (hasMultiple) {
      let typeImplicit = typeRel === "m" ? (isRel ? "l" : "L") : type;
      for (let i = chunkSize; i < values.length; i += chunkSize) {
        let chunk = values.slice(i, i + chunkSize);
        comChunks.push({
          type: typeImplicit,
          values: chunk
        });
      }
    }

    /**
     * convert to absolute
     */
    if (c === 0) {
      offX = values[0];
      offY = values[1];
      lastX = offX;
      lastY = offY;
    }

    let typeFirst = comChunks[0].type;
    typeAbs = typeFirst.toUpperCase();

    isRel =
      typeFirst.toLowerCase() === typeFirst && pathData.length ? true : false;

    for (let i = 0; i < comChunks.length; i++) {
      let com = comChunks[i];
      let type = com.type;
      let values = com.values;
      let valuesL = values.length;
      let comPrev = comChunks[i - 1] ?
        comChunks[i - 1] :
        c > 0 && pathData[pathData.length - 1] ?
        pathData[pathData.length - 1] :
        comChunks[i];

      let valuesPrev = comPrev.values;
      let valuesPrevL = valuesPrev.length;
      isRel =
        comChunks.length > 1 ?
        type.toLowerCase() === type && pathData.length :
        isRel;

      if (isRel) {
        com.type = comChunks.length > 1 ? type.toUpperCase() : typeAbs;

        switch (typeRel) {
          case "a":
            com.values = [
              values[0],
              values[1],
              values[2],
              values[3],
              values[4],
              values[5] + offX,
              values[6] + offY
            ];
            break;

          case "h":
          case "v":
            com.values = type === "h" ? [values[0] + offX] : [values[0] + offY];
            break;

          case "m":
          case "l":
          case "t":
            com.values = [values[0] + offX, values[1] + offY];
            break;

          case "c":
            com.values = [
              values[0] + offX,
              values[1] + offY,
              values[2] + offX,
              values[3] + offY,
              values[4] + offX,
              values[5] + offY
            ];
            break;

          case "q":
          case "s":
            com.values = [
              values[0] + offX,
              values[1] + offY,
              values[2] + offX,
              values[3] + offY
            ];
            break;
        }
      }
      // is absolute
      else {
        offX = 0;
        offY = 0;
      }

      // convert shorthands
      let shorthandTypes = ["H", "V", "S", "T"];

      if (shorthandTypes.includes(typeAbs)) {
        let cp1X, cp1Y, cpN1X, cpN1Y, cp2X, cp2Y;
        if (com.type === "H" || com.type === "V") {
          com.values =
            com.type === "H" ? [com.values[0], lastY] : [lastX, com.values[0]];
          com.type = "L";
        } else if (com.type === "T" || com.type === "S") {
          [cp1X, cp1Y] = [valuesPrev[0], valuesPrev[1]];
          [cp2X, cp2Y] =
          valuesPrevL > 2 ? [valuesPrev[2], valuesPrev[3]] : [valuesPrev[0], valuesPrev[1]];

          // new control point
          cpN1X = com.type === "T" ? lastX * 2 - cp1X : lastX * 2 - cp2X;
          cpN1Y = com.type === "T" ? lastY * 2 - cp1Y : lastY * 2 - cp2Y;

          com.values = [cpN1X, cpN1Y, com.values].flat();
          com.type = com.type === "T" ? "Q" : "C";
        }
      }

      // add to pathData array
      pathData.push(com);

      // update offsets
      lastX =
        valuesL > 1 ?
        values[valuesL - 2] + offX :
        typeRel === "h" ?
        values[0] + offX :
        lastX;
      lastY =
        valuesL > 1 ?
        values[valuesL - 1] + offY :
        typeRel === "v" ?
        values[0] + offY :
        lastY;
      offX = lastX;
      offY = lastY;
    }
  }

  pathData[0].type = "M";
  return pathData;
}
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 1em
}

.grd {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 1em;
}

path {
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1.5%;
}

polygon {
  marker-start: url(#markerStart);
  marker-mid: url(#markerRound);
  stroke-width: 0.5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grd">
  <div class="col">
    <h3>Path is already a polygon – skip more expensive calulations</h3>
    <svg id="svg" viewBox="10 10 94 80">
      <path id="path" fill="none" stroke="black" d="m104 33.4-6.9-16.6-16.6-6.8-16.6 6.8-6.9 16.6-6.9-16.6-16.6-6.8-16.6 6.8-6.9 16.6 9.4 23 17.5 18.3 20.1 15.3 20.1-15.3 17.5-18.3z" />
      <polygon id="poly" points="" fill="none" stroke="red" />
     </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <h3>Path has curves – retain on-path final points</h3>
    <svg id="svg1" viewBox="0 0 100 85">
      <path id="path1" fill="none" stroke="black" d="m50 85.2 33.4-27.8c9.9-9.9 16.6-17.9 16.6-32.4 0-13.7-11.2-24.9-25-24.9s-25 11.2-25 24.9c0-13.7-11.2-24.9-25-24.9s-25 11.2-25 24.9c0 16.6 8.7 24.5 16.6 32.4z" />
      <polygon id="poly1" points="" fill="none" stroke="red" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- markers -->
<svg id="svgMarkers" style="width:0; height:0; position:absolute;">
  <defs>
 <marker id="markerStart" overflow="visible" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="5" refY="5" markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10" orient="auto-start-reverse">
      <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="5" fill="green" />
 </marker>
      <marker id="markerRound" overflow="visible" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="5" refY="5" markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10" orient="auto-start-reverse">
        <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="2.5" fill="red" />
    </marker>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

#### How it works

- we're calculating each path segment's length (by creating a temporary path element)
- the desired path length division is adjusted to split the segment length evenly – so we retain the final on path points
- if a command is of type `l` lineto we omit any splitting

### 3. Close approximation

Sometimes you may need a close approximation so a highly detailed polygon mimicking a path's curvature (e.g for CSS clip-paths using `polygon()`).

When working on my custom pathLength library I came up with a helper that can auto-detect a suitable number of vertices based on a maximum length difference between path and polygon:

See [codepen path to polygon converter][5]

The vertice calculation is also based on parsing the path data so we can retain the original geometry of a path and skip additional point calculations for line segments

```js
let d = path.getAttribute("d");
let options = {
  decimals: 3,
  adaptive: true,
  retainPoly: true,
  // polygon length can deviate 0.1 length units
  tolerance: 0.1
};
let vertices = polygonFromPathData(d, options);

// show output
renderPolygon(poly, vertices);
polyPointsOut.value = "let points=" + JSON.stringify(vertices);

function renderPolygon(poly, pts) {
  let polyAtt = pts
    .map((pt) => {
      return `${pt.x} ${pt.y}`;
    })
    .join(" ");
  poly.setAttribute("points", polyAtt);
}
```

```css
svg{
  overflow:visible
}
svg path {
  stroke-width: 2%;
  stroke: #ccc;
}

svg polygon {
  stroke-width: 0.75%;
  marker-start: url(#markerStart);
  marker-mid: url(#markerRound);
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  min-height: 10em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/svg-getpointatlength@1.0.9/getPointAtLengthLookup.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/svg-getpointatlength@1.0.9/getPointAtLengthLookup_getPolygon.js"></script>
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 100 85">
  <defs>
    <marker id="markerStart" overflow="visible" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="5" refY="5" markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10" orient="auto-start-reverse">
      <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="5" fill="green" />
      < <marker id="markerRound" overflow="visible" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="5" refY="5" markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10" orient="auto-start-reverse">
        <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="2.5" fill="red" />
    </marker>
  </defs>
  <path id="path" fill="none" stroke="black" d=" m51 86.2 33.4-27.8c9.9-9.9 16.6-17.9 16.6-32.4 0-13.7-11.2-24.9-25-24.9s-25 11.2-25 24.9c0-13.7-11.2-24.9-25-24.9s-25 11.2-25 24.9c0 16.6 8.7 24.5 16.6 32.4z" />
  <polygon id="poly" points="" fill="none" stroke="red" />
  </svg>
  
<h3>Polygon vertices</h3>
<textarea id="polyPointsOut">
</textarea>
```

[1]: https://svgwg.org/specs/paths/#InterfaceSVGPathData
[2]: https://github.com/progers/pathseg
[3]: https://github.com/jarek-foksa/path-data-polyfill
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVWAD.png
[5]: https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/XWGddRm